# How to keep AzureRMAccount between sessions

Tags: powershell, azure

`Add-AzureRmAccount` or the alias `Login-AzureRmAccount` doesn't seem to persist between sessions the way that `Add-AzureAccount` does.

Is there a way to get it to persist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After adding the account to your session (either `Add-AzureRmAccount` or `Login-AzureRmAccount`,) use

```
Save-AzureRmProfile -Path <path-to-file>
```

to save the current credentials and

```
Select-AzureRmProfile -Path <path-to-file>
```

to load them.

[Thanks to Mark Cowlishaw](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/1272#issuecomment-155608348)

Comment: Opt-in saving and loading of credentials is planned, too.

Comment: I've experienced the stored credentials to expire after a couple of weeks later. Scripts using this credentials were executed each day. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Note that in the latest version of Azure Powershell, these cmdlets have been renamed to `Save-AzureRmContext` and `Import-AzureRmContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, not in the way you're used to...  It's a known issue, but I couldn't find it in the list.  Feel free to add it to:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues